# How to Calculate Visible range in Opengl ES Android?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am developing a new game for Android. In this I am using Android OpenGL ES
1.1. In this when I translate in Z axis to -2, the triangle moves backwards. Now when I translate in X axis and Y axis the triangle is visible till a limit of say -1.4 to 1.4 in Y axis and -0.8 to 0.8 in X axis.

Now If I move further down say about -4 in Z axis, I can move the triangle in 
Y-axis to say about from -1.9 to 1.9 and X- axis from -1.2 to 1.2. The numbers provided are only approximate values. The point is that when I move back wards in Z axis, I am able to move triangle for a longer range in X and Y axis. This keeps increasing as I move backwards.

Now I would like to know calculate this visible range for a given value of Z. I mean If I know the Z value to be as -3 I would like to calculate in code what is the visible range of triangle to which i can translate in X and Y axis. I right now do it manually by trying trial and error with different values. Please let me know how to calculate it in code. Thank you very much in advance for your time and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This greatly depends on what matrices you put the triangle through, or you have loaded into opengl.  Last time I checked, by default, the clip coordinates for opengl was -1 to 1 in the x, y, and z axis.

Comment: I am a bit new to Open GL ES. So can you explain a bit more. Did you mean It depends on this? If so which is the alternative Matrix mode?

Comment: Are you new to 3d graphics programming in general?  Basically what happens is you multiply a set of points by a matrix which moves these points to where you want them drawn on the screen (again, from -1 to 1 for x and y (assuming the z is also between -1 to 1).  Now, if you're using opengl1.1, then you are likely not making the matrices directly as you would with newer versions of opengl, but I'm saying that some more of your drawing code is needed.